# Drawing a dynamically updating graph with core plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-plot

I know there are some examples and discussions related to this but I am not really sure what to do achieve this. I tried reloading data continuously and some other tricks but nothing seems to make it work. The `reloadData` method in the example I am using doesn't do anything. Is there a specific thing I should add to it to make it refresh the data ?  What should I do to achieve a dynamically updating graph ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you do?

You have to change your datasource before you call reload data on the graph.

Also you can see an example in Core Plot, named "AAplot" - There they use reload data.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't think I change the datasource continuously. I set it to "self" once and thats all. I will check AAPlot though thanks for the help :)

Comment: Datasource i mean the Array/dictionary with your data. Eg if you have an array with data, then your have to change values in that specific array and then call reload, then they graph should update with the new values.

Comment: I tried reloading every possible way but for some reason it just doesn't work :/

Comment: So if you NSLog your data source before and after, you can see the difference/changes in values?

Comment: Yes, actually all the data source methods (and the data source itself) are working correctly returning correct values but for some reason the view doesn't change. I am not sure what to try..

Comment: Do you want it to move like the "Real Time Plot" in the Plot Gallery app? If so, you need to adjust the plot space ranges to accommodate the new data.